# Trigger an enter key against the text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to Jquery And I'm trying to stimulate the enter key on a text field. But its not working.

I have an textfield with id `deviceSearchByName`. I have some text typed in `deviceSearchByName` and when I press enter search results will be displayed. I'm trying this code from safari console:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13; // Enter
$("#deviceSearchByName").trigger(e)
```

Its not triggering the enter key event.

#### Edit:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
e.which = 8; // Enter
$("#deviceSearchByName").trigger(e)
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkvQK/) link. In my webpage when I press enter manually (after typing the search keyword) I get the search results. But when I trigger using JS. I dont see any event happened against that textbox and no results are been displayed.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: Check firstly which events are bound to this element, if it is keydown, keyup or keypress or... `$._data($("#deviceSearchByName")[0],'events')`

Comment: its giving me `Object {keyup: Array[2]}`

Comment: so it's keyup you are looking for, not keydown

Comment: so I have to change it keyup?

Comment: I edited my question with keyup, its not working either.

Comment: 8 is not an keycode for keyup?

Comment: `$("#deviceSearchByName")` has `keyup` event. I'm new to JS. I guess `keyup` event code is `8`. That is the reason me passing `8`.

Comment: keyup is an event, e.which is the targeted key, try keyup with `e.which = 13;` where 13 refering to Enter key... If you don't provide a jsfiddle, i'll stop to speak in the wind...

Comment: No it is not working. This is the code I'm trying :
`Var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
e.which = 13; // Enter
$("#deviceSearchByName").trigger(e);` but nothing is happening.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RkvQK/ here is the link. Edited the question as well.

Comment: "Could you provide a jsfiddle **which replicates your issue** ?" ... In the 'basic' jsfiddle you provided, i don't see any result when i press Enter... Maybe you could tell what are these results? Where it comes from? Etc... Instead of being focused on How to trigger an event. Calling a function is always cleaner

Comment: Please don't tell me you are trying to access the content of a cross domain iframe, please don't

Comment: This is the text box code, the webpage isn't available to public. `<input type="search" id="deviceSearchByName" placeholder="e.g. n90ap" onsearch="device.search(event);" title="Device Name" results="5" style="width:100px;height:15px;font-size:10px;">`

Comment: @A.Wolff Without the code in the actual question, this question won't be helpful to future visitors if the code on the website ever changes. Please don't ask for a link to a website, ask that users post the relevant code that reproduces the issue into their question.

Comment: @sriram Please edit the code into your question; anything that's in the JS fiddle should be in the question (not the comments) in case JSFiddle goes down (which happens a lot).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Ya, sorry, but as i asked many times OP to provide relevant code, i forgive and simply ask him where i can check his issue. My bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see here (http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) that trigger can have two arguments. One for the event and one for extra parameters.

So you need to do :

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13; // Enter
$("#deviceSearchByName").trigger('keydown', e);
```

Comment: No, OP was using the right way to trigger event, passing an event as argument

Comment: No it is the same as I did.

Comment: @sriram it's not exactly the same, using this answer, event.which inside handler will be undefined, your code pass it to the event object